# Avoiding Implied globals in javascript (JSlint)

Tags: javascript, jslint

When writing code like this jsLint complains about implied globals:

```
var Test = (function(){
    var fnc = function(x){
        alert("pew: "+x);
    };

    return {
        fnc: fnc
    };
}());

Test.fnc("hat");
```

(specifically, 'Implied global: alert 4')

What is considered the correct way to avoid this? My instinctive response is this, but I'm not convinced it is 'correct':

```
var Test2 = (function(global){
    var alert = global.alert;

    var fnc = function(x){
        alert("pew: "+x);
    };

    return {
        fnc: fnc
    };
}(this));

Test2.fnc("hat");
```

Edit:
The consensus seems to be that the problem isn't the fact that I'm accessing a global, it's more that I'm not telling jslint what the globals are. I'll leave this open a little longer to see if anyone else has input, then I'll pick an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prepend your file with a comment

`/*global alert $ document window*/`

This is generally how I tell JSLint that it's not implied but external.

This is both unobtrusive as well as telling your fellow programmers that your declaring these variables as external which is useful for larger multi-file programs.

Comment: IIRC don't the variable name declarations need to be comma-separated?

Comment: @ZackTheHuman there space seperated. Turns out JSLint says there comma seperated. I've always used a space seperated list without errors. It probably handles both

Comment: Note that there should not be a space between start of the comment and `global` otherwise jslint does not process it.

Answer (score 4):

Use jsLint's "assume a browser" and "Assume console, alert, ..." options to make those functions known to jsLint.
See http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options for a list of all available options.

Answer (score 1):

For those searching for JSHint instead, there is an option "browser" which can be set to "true" and handles all the common globals. Same for "jquery". I learned this from the [gradle-js-plugin source code](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin/blob/9a5f51c74ede55750825fb78bd491467934c87a5/src/main/resources/jshint-rhino-r12.js).

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is correct(and good too), but there is no need to declare `global.alert` ,  just use `global.alert("pew: "+x);`

Comment: The `var alert = global.alert` is really just for convenience, so it behaves the same as it would if I just left the error in.

Comment: I don't see any convenience by using it. But regardless of this part, I think your solution is not only correct, it's good.